# Field Collection Adding Values

Tags: entities

I'm confused by the field_collection API. I created a Field Collection and attached it to a node (in the GUI) but I can't figure out how to code an update/addition to the field collection. This is my scenario:

I have a node (request) that has product information and quantities. When users go to a product page they see a link to "Add to Request". This link should add the product (nid) to the node request. The difficulty lies in the fact that I need quantity information as well, hence the Field Collection. I added a quantities field and grouped it with the product field.

**Node Type: request

Request ID: $requestid

Product ID: $productid

Field Collection = field_request_collection (Unlimited values) 

Field Collection Field = field_products (Entity Reference, Max 1) 

Field Collection Field = field_product_quantities (Integer, Max 1, Default 1)**

My function looks like this (the values for $requestid and $productid are passed in the URL of the link: /my_request/5/12):

```
function _my_module_request_update($requestid,$productid) {
$nload = node_load($requestid);
$field_collection_item_value = $nload->field_request_collection[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
$field_collection_item = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($field_collection_item_value));
$field_collection_item->field_products[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = intval($productid);
$field_collection_item->save();
}
```

The error I'm getting with the above code is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function `save()` on a non-object

Keep in mind that I'm attempting to ADD Field Collection values NOT replace them.  Please help, thanks!

Comment: Looks like your `entity_load()` is failing. What do you get for the `$field_collection_item` object when you inspect it?

Comment: I'm trying to the pull the field collection entity so I can set the value of a field in that collection.

Comment: This works fine to load all field_collections: entity_load('field_collection_item') but when I try to grab this one: entity_load('field_collection_item', array('field_request_collection')); it gives me an empty array.

Comment: So I had to use the entity id which in this case is 1(I only have a single field collection as of now). So: entity_load('field_collection_item', array('1'));

Comment: So I figured out how to REPLACE the value of an existing field. This is on https://drupal.org/node/1842304. However, I want to ADD a new value as this is a multi-value field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
$nload = node_load($requestid);
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_request_collection'));
$field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $nload);
$field_collection_item->field_products[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = intval($productid);
$field_collection_item->save();

$nload->field_request_collection[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = $field_collection_item->item_id;
```

Comment: I was working on the same code but I'm getting caught up with this: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'field_products_target_id' cannot be null:

Comment: Ah ok, field_products is an entity reference. I'll update the answer

Comment: Tip: After $field_collection_item->save(); the Field collection entity is already attached to the Host entity.